# How can I create circle polyline or Accuracy Circle in Bing Map V8

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, bing-maps

I already have Accuracy Circle in Bing Map v7, However It can't work when I'm using Bing Maps v8.

How can I create circle polyline or Accuracy Circle in Bing Map V8

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is here to help you with a specific issue that you encounter in your code, not to give you all the code like magic...

Comment: geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);
          geoLocationProvider.addAccuracyCircle(InitLocation, 5000, 5000, {
              polygonOptions: {
                  fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(0, 0, 0,0),
                  strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255,255,0,0),
                  strokeThickness: 2,
                  strokeDashArray: "30 5 5 5 "

              }
          });

----> But this not working on Bing Maps V8

Comment: Please Edit your question and add the code... If you click on Help when you edit your post, you will see there is possibility to have syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps V8 SDK not longer has a GeoLocationProvider class. This was added in v7 which was released over 6 years ago. When it was released no browsers had any geolocation capabilities. Now, all major browsers have a built in HTML5 Geolocation API and there is no longer a need for this workaround class that was in v7. You can find an article on how to use the HTML5 geolocation API with V8 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712802.aspx

These samples currently don't show how to create an accuracy circle as the spatial math library wasn't available yet which makes this really easy. In this library is a static function called getRegularPolygon (docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712834.aspx). It returns an array of locations that form a regular polygon around a location with a specified radius. If you generate a regular polygon that has 30 or more points, it will look like a circle. There is however a bug in this spatial math function in that it is meant to default to meters but is instead using KM's instead. I've put together a code sample that draws an accuracy circle around the users location and added a minor work around for the current bug. This work around will continue to work even after the bug is fixed so you don't need to worry about it breaking in the future. Here is the code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap'
            async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap() {
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
        });

        //Load the spatial math module
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath", function () {
            //Request the user's location
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);

                //Create an accuracy circle
                var accuracyRadiusMeters = position.coords.accuracy;

                var path = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(loc, accuracyRadiusMeters/1000, 30,  Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.KM);
                var poly = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(path);
                map.entities.push(poly);           

                //Add a pushpin at the user's location.
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
                map.entities.push(pin);

                //Center the map on the user's location.
                map.setView({ center: loc, zoom: 17 });
            });
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```